# Change Button Text after click back

Tags: javascript, html, web, button

Dear StackOverflow Community,

I have this Code to copy the URL to the Clipboard. The problem is, after clicked it stays on "kopiert". I want it to change back. I know that this question is asked 100x times and there is code on the Internet. My problem is, that I dont know much of programming and tried the codes on the web. Couldnt implement it. I really need help. Am really thankful for any.

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
<div class="background">
<center>
  <button class="clipboard">Link kopieren</button>
</center>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $temp = $("<input>");
var $url = $(location).attr('href');

$('.clipboard').on('click', function() {
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($url).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
    $("button").text("kopiert!");
})
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) here to run a function that is delayed by a set amount of time. For example, we could update your JavaScript to be:

```js
var $temp = $("<input>");
var $url = $(location).attr('href');

$('.clipboard').on('click', function() {
    const originalText = $("button").text();

    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($url).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
    $("button").text("kopiert!");

    // Run something in 2.5 seconds to revert back to the button's text
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("button").text(originalText);
    }, 2500); // 2.5 seconds
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I directly tried that and it did work :)

Comment: Yeah, will do. I just need to wait 3 minutes so that StackOverflow allows it ;D